# Override lazy OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Have an entity with a OneToMany relationship in Spring Data that I would need to filter by a specific column. I've been unable to find a satisfying solution to get it with a single query (both parent entity and the filtered OneToMany in one go) so I'm now thinking in having it lazy fetched and after getting the parent entity, have a separate query to retrieve the linked entities and just using a setter to link them together (ie: parent.setChildren(childrenRepository.findAllBy...)).

Question is: would this effectively disable any future trigger to the lazy fetch so my manually set children would remain? Use case here is to add these children manually in certain cases, and using the default lazy fetch when the conditions don't apply.

I tested this and seems to be working as intended, but could not find information on when the lazy fetch should be triggered as to make sure my logic would work in any scenario (is it disabled as soon as the setter is invoked? is this documented anywhere?)

Thanks in advance.